# Python trying to Refactor (DRY out) a long Control Flow

Tags: python, refactoring, dry, python-2.5, control-flow

I am grabbing a lot of data from and SQL query that takes a long time to run. Since the SQL query takes so long to run, I am grabbing the data from the database in its most granular form. I then cycle through this data once and aggregate it in the forms that are useful to me.

My problem is that I am repeating myself over and over again. However, I am not sure of the best way to refactor this control flow. Thanks in advance!

```
def processClickOutData(cls, raw_data):
    singles = {}
    total={}
    absolute_total = 0
    channels = {}

    singles_true = {}
    total_true={}
    channels_true = {}
    absolute_total_true = 0

    list_channels = set([])
    list_tids = set([])


    total_position = {}
    total_position_true = {}
    tid_position = {}
    channel_position = {}
    channel_position_true = {}
    tid_position_true = {}

    for row in raw_data:
        gap=row[0]
        count=row[1]
        tid=row[2]
        prefered=row[3]
        channel=row[4]
        position=row[5]

        list_channels.add(channel)
        list_tids.add(tid)


        absolute_total += int(count)

        if total.has_key(gap):
            total[gap] += count
        else:
            total[gap] = count

        if singles.has_key(gap) and singles[gap].has_key(tid):
            singles[gap][tid] += count
        elif singles.has_key(gap):
            singles[gap][tid] = count
        else:
            singles[gap] = {}
            singles[gap][tid] = count

        if channels.has_key(gap) and channels[gap].has_key(channel):
            channels[gap][channel] += count
        elif channels.has_key(gap):
            channels[gap][channel] = count
        else:
            channels[gap] = {}
            channels[gap][channel] = count
        if total_position.has_key(position):
            total_position[position] += count
        else:
            total_position[position] = count
        if tid_position.has_key(position) and tid_position[position].has_key(tid):
            tid_position[position][tid] += count     
        elif tid_position.has_key(position):
            tid_position[position][tid] = count
        else:
            tid_position[position] = {}
            tid_position[position][tid] = count

        if channel_position.has_key(position) and channel_position[position].has_key(channel):
            channel_position[position][channel] += count     
        elif channel_position.has_key(position):
            channel_position[position][channel] = count
        else:
            channel_position[position] = {}
            channel_position[position][channel] = count

        if prefered == 0:
            absolute_total_true += count
            if total_true.has_key(gap):
                total_true[gap] += count
            else:
                total_true[gap] = count

            if singles_true.has_key(gap) and singles_true[gap].has_key(tid):
                singles_true[gap][tid] += count
            elif singles_true.has_key(gap):
                singles_true[gap][tid] = count
            else:
                singles_true[gap] = {}
                singles_true[gap][tid] = count

            if channels_true.has_key(gap) and channels_true[gap].has_key(channel):
               channels_true[gap][channel] += count
            elif channels_true.has_key(gap):
               channels_true[gap][channel] = count
            else:
               channels_true[gap] = {}
               channels_true[gap][channel] = count

            if total_position_true.has_key(position):
               total_position_true[position] += count
            else:
               total_position_true[position] = count 

            if tid_position_true.has_key(position) and tid_position_true[position].has_key(tid):
               tid_position_true[position][tid] += count     
            elif tid_position_true.has_key(position):
               tid_position_true[position][tid] = count
            else:
               tid_position_true[position] = {}
               tid_position_true[position][tid] = count

            if channel_position_true.has_key(position) and channel_position_true[position].has_key(channel):
               channel_position_true[position][channel] += count     
            elif channel_position_true.has_key(position):
               channel_position_true[position][channel] = count
            else:
               channel_position_true[position] = {}
               channel_position_true[position][channel] = count




    final_values = {"singles" : singles, "singles_true" : singles_true, "total" : total, "total_true": total_true, "absolute_total": absolute_total, "absolute_total_true": absolute_total_true, "channel_totals" : channels, "list_channels" : list_channels, "list_tids" : list_tids, "channel_totals_true" : channels_true,
                     "total_position" :  total_position, "total_position_true" : total_position_true, "tid_position" : tid_position, "channel_position" : channel_position, "tid_position_true" : tid_position_true, "channel_position_true" : channel_position_true }
    return final_values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire structure you're using to store the data is probably wrong, but since I don't know how you're using it, I can't help you with that.

You can get rid of **all** of those `has_key()` calls by using [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Note `thedict.has_key(key)` is deprecated anyway, you should just use `key in thedict` instead.

Look at how I change the `for` loop too -- you can assign to names right in the `for` statement, no need to do it separately.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def processClickOutData(cls, raw_data):
    absolute_total = 0
    absolute_total_true = 0

    list_channels = set()
    list_tids = set()

    total = defaultdict(int)
    total_true = defaultdict(int)
    total_position = defaultdict(int)
    total_position_true = defaultdict(int)

    def defaultdict_int():
        return defaultdict(int)

    singles = defaultdict(defaultdict_int)
    singles_true = defaultdict(defaultdict_int)
    channels = defaultdict(defaultdict_int)
    channels_true = defaultdict(defaultdict_int)
    tid_position = defaultdict(defaultdict_int)
    tid_position_true = defaultdict(defaultdict_int)
    channel_position = defaultdict(defaultdict_int)
    channel_position_true = defaultdict(defaultdict_int)    

    for gap, count, prefered, channel, position in raw_data:
        list_channels.add(channel)
        list_tids.add(tid)

        absolute_total += count
        total[gap] += count
        singles[gap][tid] += count
        channels[gap][channel] += count
        total_position[position] += count
        tid_position[position][tid] += count
        channel_position[position][channel] += count

        if prefered == 0:
            absolute_total_true += count
            total_true[gap] += count
            singles_true[gap][tid] += count
            channels_true[gap][channel] += count
            total_position_true[position] += count
            tid_position_true[position][tid] += count
            channel_position_true[position][channel] += count




    final_values = {"singles" : singles, "singles_true" : singles_true, "total" : total, "total_true": total_true, "absolute_total": absolute_total, "absolute_total_true": absolute_total_true, "channel_totals" : channels, "list_channels" : list_channels, "list_tids" : list_tids, "channel_totals_true" : channels_true,
                     "total_position" :  total_position, "total_position_true" : total_position_true, "tid_position" : tid_position, "channel_position" : channel_position, "tid_position_true" : tid_position_true, "channel_position_true" : channel_position_true }
    return final_values
```

What this does is automatically fill in the correct default values if the keys don't exist. You've got two kinds here. Where you're adding `int`s, you want to start with `0` if it doesn't exist -- that's what `int` returns, hence `defaultdict(int)`. Where you're adding a dictionary that adds `int`s, you need to use a function that returns a `defaultdict(int)` which is what `defaultdict_int` does.

**Edit:** Suggested alternate dictionary structure:

```
position = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(defaultdict_int))
gap = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(defaultdict_int))
absolute_total = 0

for gap, count, prefered, channel, position in raw_data:
    absolute_total += count

    posd = position[position]
    posd.setdefault('total', 0)
    posd['total'] += count
    posd['tid'][tid] += count
    posd['channel'][channel] += count

    gapd = gap[gap]
    gapd.setdefault('total', 0)
    gapd['total'] += count
    gapd['tid'][tid] += count
    gapd['channel'][channel] += count
```

Do the same with the `_true` versions as well, and you've gone from 12 `dict`s to 4.

Comment: what do you mean the entire structure I am using to store data is wrong? The output is correct, I am checking the data against SQL queries performing the same functio.

Comment: @Peter I've added an example of what I mean to my answer. Basically, having twelve dicts like that is pretty disorganized, four does the exact same thing.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to Python and programming in general so this is very very helpful. I up-voted and now will accept.